# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory issue

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

This is the gradle dependencies. (UPDATED)

```
   compile group: 'net.sf.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '2.10.4'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.8.RELEASE'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'

compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.20.0'
```

this code generates the error.

```
   HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory =
                new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory)
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("1009293319809-dek5gcam0af2c52ute611c8p51cfvker.apps.googleusercontent.com"))
                // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
                //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
                .build();
```

Received error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
... 70 common frames omitted
```

[image]

Any idea of what library I am missing. I am assuming there is maybe conflict of libraries. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows 2 versions of the `google-api-client` library:

[image]

Also, you are importing the library twice in your gradle build file:

```
compile group: 'com.google.api.client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.4.1-beta'
...
compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.20.0'
```

The fact that you get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` seems to be caused by the fact that the older version of the library does not contain the mentioned class and it is overriding the most recent version of the library.
All you need to do is remove the reference to the older version of the library (1.4.1-beta) from your gradle file.

Comment: I thought the class in question found in `google-http-client-jackson`

Comment: @Yohannes The tags are a little misleading. The error message clearly states the class not being found: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory`

Comment: @LouisBono I removed the beta but still it doesnt work. I put jackson tag because I am suspecting that can be also conflicting.

Comment: @legend12345 Are you getting the same error? Please post the details.

Comment: @LouisBono same as I wrote above. only now gradle has only 1.20.0 but still        
    
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
 ... 70 common frames omitted

Comment: @legend12345 I also noticed more duplicate dependencies (e.g., `google-http-client-jackson` and `google-http-client-jackson2`). I suggest keeping your dependencies clean, the result of dependency duplication always results in `NoClassDefFoundError`s or `NoSuchMethoderror`s.

Comment: @legend12345 Actually, the exception changed from `NoClassDefFoundError` to `ClassNotFoundException`. Please see me previous comment on cleaning up your dependencies. I just tried to guess which jar file might be containing the missing class, but my point is that you should see the error disappear after cleaning up your dependencies.

Comment: @legend12345 I think this is the main page of the library you are using: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/. You might want to have a look and be sure you are importing all the required dependencies and using the right versions.

Comment: @legend12345 I had a look at the updated info. It seems that your application server can't load the class on startup. I am assuming that the code compiles with no errors on your machine. If the class is missing at startup, you may want to check that the WAR file (or whatever deployment option you chose) contains the required JAR files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp.

Comment: @LouisBono of course.  yes I am trying to run the tomcat and it ends up like this.

Comment: @legend12345 You might want to edit your question again. The code you mentioned probably has nothing to do with the stacktrace, which is related to Tomcat not being able to start your webapp.

Comment: @legend12345 I had also edited my previous comment, so you may have missed the additional suggestions. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155284/discussion-between-legend12345-and-louis-bono).